# Problem in lounching debugger vs-code ms-python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I started working on a project I left 6 months ago.
The project is in ms-code, ms-python extension.
I made all the updates to the vs-code and the extensions.

When I start the debugger I get the following message:

> timeout waiting for debugger connection

I know that there are problems in launch.jeson (it says some of the fields are not allowed)

I renamed the launch.jason so that it will create a new one and got the same message.

I managed to activate the program in the powershell window
Ilan

**old launch.jason**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: main.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\main.py"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "port": 3000,
            "secret": "my_secret",
            "host": "localhost"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Terminal (integrated)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Terminal (external)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput",
                "Django"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask (0.11.x or later)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "module.name"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Pyramid",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/development.ini"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput",
                "Pyramid"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Watson",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/console.py",
            "args": [
                "dev",
                "runserver",
                "--noreload=True"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: All debug Options",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "module": "module.name",
            "env": {
                "VAR1": "1",
                "VAR2": "2"
            },
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "args": [
                "arg1",
                "arg2"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**new launch.jason (generated by the extension - not touched by me**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5678,
            "host": "localhost"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "enter-your-module-name-here",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "django": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (External Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Last resort would be uninstall vs code and start fresh. Second last would be to Delete .vscode folder, doing that would delete all the settings and preferences also. Third last would be before deleting, try renaming the folder .vscode to something else and start the vscode again. See if it solves the problem.

Comment: If you are using conda w/ PowerShell it's a known issue due to conda's lack of PowerShell support. If you switch to Command Prompt or disable automatic terminal activation with `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false` that should take care of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Brett. That solved the problem